# How can I keep my draw function while using dom positioning in datatables?

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables, draw

I am loading thumbnails into my datatable via draw.dt function:

```
  var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
     //... code
  });

  $('.datatable').on( 'draw.dt', function() {
    loadThumbnails();
  });
```

This works well, but I try now to display my pagination into the header, so I am adding:

```
   var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
       "dom": '<"col-sm-6"<"dataTables_length"l>><"col-sm-6"<"dataTables_filter"p>><"clear">',
  });
```

But now my thumbnails are not loaded anymore.

Comment: You miss `t` for table ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `t` for table, try with

```js
dom: '<"col-sm-6"<"dataTables_length"l>><"col-sm-6"<"dataTables_filter"p>>"clear">t',
```

If you not use `t` the table itself is omitted.